# The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

My code is given below i get this error :

```
The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

It points to `Temp1(i) = ( ( X(i,1)*theta(i,1) + X(i,2)*theta(i,2) ) - y(i));`

I dont understand what is wrong here. Please help

```
Temp1 = zeros(m);
sum1 = 0;
for i = 1:1:m
{
    Temp1(i) = ( ( X(i,1)*theta(i,1) + X(i,2)*theta(i,2) ) - y(i));

    sum1 = sum1 + (Temp1(i)^2);
}

J = sum1 / (2*m);
fprintf(' The value of J = ');
fprintf('%f', J);
return J;
```

Comment: You don't use braces as delimiters for for loops in matlab. You use `end`.

Comment: nor do you return value that way from a function

Answer (score 2):

You could vectorize that entire code as:

```
J = sum( (sum(X.*theta,2) - y).^2 ) ./ (2*m);
```

Comment: As has been discussed elsewhere - vectorizing code no longer provides as big a performance improvement given the improvements in Matlab's JIT compiler. Also this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @mutzmatron: MATLAB is by design better optimized to work on whole vectors/matrices. While JIT accelaration has come a long way, cases like this are prime examples of where vectorization is best. MathWorks itself [recommends](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f8-784135.html#br8fs0d-1) it.

Comment: Correct - I wasn't arguing that it doesn't still provide an improvement (or is recommended by MathWorks).  But in terms of helping the OP find the mistake in their code, your answer doesn't help.

Comment: @mutzmatron: now users who are getting started with MATLAB often use programming style they are used to from other languages. IMO it is always helpful to show them the preferred MATLAB-way... You can disagree with me, but I have been active in the MATLAB tag a long time to know that a lot of people find this type of improvements helpful

Comment: While I agree that showing someone how to vectorize is a useful *comment*, your answer was not an answer. Also I think it was far more useful to correct their syntax for a `for` loop...

Answer (score 1):

Your code should read

```
Temp1 = zeros(m);
sum1 = 0;
for i = 1:1:m

    Temp1(i) = ( ( X(i,1)*theta(i,1) + X(i,2)*theta(i,2) ) - y(i));

    sum1 = sum1 + (Temp1(i)^2);
end


J = sum1 / (2*m);

fprintf(' The value of J = ');
fprintf('%f', J);
```

ie you don't use braces, instead a for loop has the syntax:

```
for i=1:10
    .
    .
    .
end
```

Comment: you should remove that `return` statement, it's not a valid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not directly answer your question, I believe you may have a misunderstanding about the results to a call to `zeros(m)`. That will actually make an `m x m` matrix of zeros. Based on the code above, it looks like you're only treating the temp variable as a vector. Try `zeros(m,1)` to make a vector instead.

Comment: Actually this is fine - while probably not intended, it is fine to linearly index into a matrix - see here http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#f1-85511

Comment: @mutzmatron I'm not saying it's not possible -- I'm saying I don't think it's what the OP intended to do. But thanks for the downvote anyway.

Comment: This comment should be a comment on the original question then as it doesn't actually answer the question, right?

Comment: @mutzmatron Fair enough. Not sure it's necessary to downvote it as I believe it's valuable regardless, but I suppose you're correct that it doesn't necessarily answer the original question. Keep up the great policing.

Comment: I still don't understand the value in your answer, given that linear indexing is fine. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @mutzmatron The value is that the OP very likely has a misconception about what a call to `zeros()` actually produces. This answer would clear that up. Linear indexing is indeed "fine", but almost certainly is not what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14419/discussion-between-mutzmatron-and-aardvarkk)

Comment: I agree that this is also a helpful answer. The OP obviously wanted a vector not a matrix